# AHK: GetKeyState, can't send 2 commands

Tags: autohotkey

Basically what I want to do is: While I hold down the "a"-key the script automatically holds and releases the "a"-key over and over. It also has to press or hold/release the "h"-key. It causes me problems when I try to add the "h"-key (it spams the "h"-key whenever I activate the script instead of waiting for an "a"-press).

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, Clicking

F2::ExitApp

Clicking:

a::
if (GetKeyState("a", "P"))
   Send {a down} 
   Send {h down} 
   Sleep 100
   Send {h up} 
   Send {a up} 
   Sleep 475

Return 

a up:: Send {a up}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need braces around your if block:

```
if (GetKeyState("a", "P"))
{
   Send {a down} 
   Send {h down} 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That fixed it!